phpmyadmin database backup with laravel
Hi everyone I'm creating a schedule command with Laravel Forge that should backup the db in phpmyadmin once a day, but the problem is that it creates an empty sql file this is my code I hope someone can help me understand where the problem is many thanks in advance
In debug mode this is error : ""mysqldump"" is not recognized as an internal or external command, an executable program or batch file. this is error in log shell
public function handle()
    {
        $dbname = "backup-" . Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d') . ".sql";

        $command = "mysqldump --user=" . env('DB_USERNAME') . " --password=" . env('DB_PASSWORD')
            . " --host=" . env('DB_HOST') . " " . env('DB_DATABASE')
            . " > " . storage_path() . "/app/private/backup/" . $dbname;

        $returnVar = NULL;
        $output = NULL;

        exec($command, $output, $returnVar);

        return Command::SUCCESS;
    }

filesystem.php

 'disks' => [

  .....
        'private' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/private'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL') . '/storage',
            'visibility' => 'private',
            'throw' => false,
        ],

....
    ],

database.php

'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'modes' => [
                //'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY', // Disable this to allow grouping by one column
                'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
                'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
                'NO_ZERO_DATE',
                'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
                'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER',
                'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
            ],
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],

env .

I expect an export of the complete db with all the tables but the file is empty, I don't understand where the problem is
Resolved - New code work with command Artisan
$azienda = User::value('azienda');

        $dbname = $azienda . Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d') . ".sql";

        $command = "mysqldump --user=" . env('DB_USERNAME') . " --password=" . env('DB_PASSWORD')
            . " --host=" . env('DB_HOST') . " " . env('DB_DATABASE')
            . " > " . storage_path() . "/app/private/backup/" . $dbname;

        $returnVar = NULL;
        $output = NULL;

        exec($command, $output, $returnVar);

        Artisan::call('mysql-dump');

        return Command::SUCCESS;


instead of creating the dump yourself, there are packages available to backup your database for example https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-backup/v8/taking-backups/overview

thanks but I can't install it

I managed to install by removing the ; in the php.ini file on extension:gd

FYI, you're not backing up "phpmyadmin", you're backing up a MySQL database. phpmyadmin is just a GUI for the database, it isn't the database.

i run the code and it work fine.
i think your problem is in your permissions.
1.check that you have permission to write to /app/private/backup/ directory
2.check if the user in mysql have the permission to backup the database
why did you commented the return

hi, how do I check the write permissions can you show me the way? place the filesystem.php code

to check permissions to write in /app/private/backup/ run this
Get-Acl -Path "storage\app\private\backup" in powershell
to check permissions to backup database run this
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'username'@'host';
replace your_username with the DB_USERNAME in environment and your_host with your host if local 127.0.0.1
If the user does not have the necessary privileges, give it privileges by
GRANT SELECT, LOCK TABLES, SHOW VIEW ON database.* TO 'username'@'host';
Replace database your database.

hi, thanks I checked and I have FullControll, but I can't understand why it creates an empty sql file with 0 bytes... incredible

did you check permissions to backup database

yess, all permission.. but not work

Check mysqldump Command Manually:
try running the mysqldump command manually in your terminal to ensure that the command itself works correctly with your database credentials.
mysqldump --user=your_db_user --password=your_db_password --host=your_db_host your_database_name > test_backup.sql


@Moreno show me the output of the .env file

I posted envarioment file for what I can show because it contains other sensitive data

command bash not work and not recognized

""mysqldump"" is not recognized as an internal or external command,
an executable program or batch file. this is error in log shell

this is your problem mysql is not in your environment add mysql to your environment.


locate the path to your mysql/bin directory and copy the path of bin directory


in your windows search, search for edit the system environment variables.


click environment variables in the bottom, in system variables double click on path variable.


click new and paste the path of the mysql/bin, click ok


then you should can run your backup command
if this help mark my answer

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

hi unfortunately, even by arranging the environment variables I was unable to create the complete sql file, it still generates an empty sql. I don't know what else to do

Resolved. In practice, an artisan command was missing thanks to everyone, I'll post the new code for anyone who needs it in the future and please move up the level thanks
